# phpmyadmin - users can't edit events

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem where a user can create events but once created, can't edit or drop. They have full privilidges on the database but no super privilidges.

I can't find a soloution for this anywhere, please help.

Comment: Grant them the UPDATE & DELETE privileges?

Comment: They have all privilidges for their database

Comment: Then I couldn't tell you what's wrong without an exact error message.

Comment: There is no error message, the options to EDIT and DROP are greyed out

Comment: Well, without an error message, it's a software problem, not a coding problem...

Comment: What phpMyAdmin version do you have?

Comment: Is the user unable to edit/drop events even if that user is the one who created them? Are you adding any specific DEFINER (more specifically, as another user)?

Comment: The user who creates the EVENT, can't EDIT nor DROP them. And no I'm not adding any specific DEFINERS.

Currently only an account with super privileges can EDIT or DROP.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?